# SNMP Traps: Telling the difference between sources

Tags: snmp

I am logging all incoming SNMP traps to file, for further processing, via:

```
snmptrapd -Lf /path/to/my/file.log
```

So this will log all traps coming in on port 162. Is there a way I can tell the differences between different sources, i.e vendors. I believe this would be the "OID" field but i'm unsure. Any thoughts would be welcomed, if not I will just have to use a lookup with IP addresses, but I'm sure I saw that there is a unique part to each vendor.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is my solution, not an answer but I will close the question off...

So I made sure that I formatted the SNMP that was written to file with my own requirements, so I would know where the community string was... at least that way I could have a unique community string reference.

I used the following command...

`snmptrapd -Lf /path/to/file/snmptrapd.log -F %y-%m-%l %h-:%j - %b(%B) - Security=%P - Payload=%v\n\n`